# Removal of special characters in argument using bash

Tags: shell

I wanna remove ( and )  from given argument using bash script. Pls help me out. Sed command used for removing other spl characters is not working over here

Comment: Could you give example what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Given argument is ((12234.())  I need to output 12234

Comment: Which `sed` command are you using? On what example does it not work? Which characters do you treat as "not special"? Give us a [MCVE].

Comment: I was using sed 's/[\. ()] //g'

Comment: If special character is punctuation character,  try to use character class [:punct:] . Command is  " echo '((12234.())' | sed -r 's@[[:punct:]]*@@g' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just got an extra space in the `sed` command you gave in the comments. This causes the regex to only replace any of those characters "plus a space" (for example it converts `a. b` into `ab`, but it won't just match a single `.` without the space, so `a.b` remains `a.b`).

You should use `sed 's/[. ()]//g'` instead. For example:

```
$ echo "((ab.))(" | sed 's/[. ()]//g'
ab
```

Note that this is with GNU `sed` - other versions may behave differently.

Also be aware that the `.` doesn't need to be escaped here because it's in a character set (`[...]`). If used unescaped outside of a character set, it behaves as a single-character wildcard as normal.

Answer (score 0):

In your example (given in comment) yiu want to change

`((12234.())` to `11234`

Now this can be achieve several way. You can do this

`sed -e "s/[()]//g" input.txt`

This will remove all character between box bracket.

Or you can do this

`sed -e "s/[^0-9]//g" input.txt`

This will remove any character that not a numbers.

Update:

I try in bash you dont have to escap dot character (.) so you can do something like this

`sed -e "s/[().]//g" input.txt`

Comment: Note that the only reason the `.` doesn't need to be escaped is because it's in a character set (`[...]`) - it's not to do with `bash`. If it's not used in a character set (eg. `sed 's/.//g'`), then it still behaves as a single-character wildcard as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash script:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "${1//[(.)]/}"
```

Run it:

```
$ bash foo.sh "((12234.())"
12234
```